# large deviation, contraction principle

Tags: probability-theory, large-deviation-theory

Let $X_1, X_2, ... , X_n$ be i.i.d. normal random variables with mean $0$ and variance $1$.
I want to show that the random variables $Y_n := 1/(2n^2) \sum_{i,j =1}^n X_i X_j$  satisfy a large deviation principle with rate function.
$I(a)=a$ if $a \geq 0 $ and $I(a) = \infty$ if $ a<0$.

This should be possible by using the contraction principle.
However, I do not see how I can use the contraction principle to say something about $X_i*X_j$ and hence about the given sum.

Comment: What are $a$ and the function $I(a)$ here?

Comment: They are just the input of the function $I$. So you can read it as the function $I$ being the identity function for input greater than zero and $I$ being infinity for inputs smaller than $0$.